# Extend ellipsoid by given radius

Tags: geometry

I have a parameterization of an ellipsoid, given by
\begin{align}
x &= a\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\
y &= b\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z &= c\cos(\theta)\,,
\end{align}
where $\theta$ is the elevation angle and $\phi$ is the azimuth angle. Since I have $b = c$, I believe it is called an spheroid in my case.

I would like to extend the ellipsoid by a radius $R$, i.e., each point $\mathbf{p} = (x, y, z)$ on the ellipsoid should be replaced by $\mathbf{p}' = \mathbf{p} + R\,\mathbf{n}$, where $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal vector at point $\mathbf{p}$.

I assume the new surface will be an ellipsoid again, but I am not sure how to derive this. Is there an easier approach than calculating the gradient and the corresponding normal vector?

Comment: It's not an ellipsoid, sorry!

Comment: @ProfessorVector This is already good to know. Thank you! How do you know it's not an ellipsoid? However, I still have to create that surface as described. Is there a way to directly calculate the normal vector for a given point on the ellipsoid?

Comment: If it were, the volume would be $\frac43\pi (a+R)(b+R)(c+R)=\frac43\pi(abc+(ab+bc+ac)R+o(R))$, i.e. the surface area of the ellipsoid would be $\frac43\pi(ab+bc+ac)$ (by the Steiner-Minkovski-formula). As you probably know, it's not that simple in reality.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2857219